# How can we know a new contact is Added to Android?

Tags: android

Hello Guys i m using following code to open Android Add Contact Page ,

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
        intent1.setType(Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        intent1.setData(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent1,300);
```

But as a result code it sends -1 inside onActivityResult function
I want to have the ContactId of the newly added Person , How can we get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the Response fron Android Add Contact View by making foloowing function in our activity

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && requestCode==300) {

        AddNewlyReceivedcontact(ContentUris.parseId(data.getData()));

    }
}
```

Here AddNewlyReceivedcontact is not a android function, it's a user defined function.

Answer (score 0):

When there is error in adding a contact to the the contacts database it will return -1 else it returns the ContactId of the contact.

Try using the following code:

```
Intent intent1= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent1,300);
```

Comment: i am not having any problem in adding contact but having problem in fetching the id of contact added.